# iPad Crashes on Start Up Using Xamarin.Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have been trying to test and debug on my iPad but I have not been able to get it to work. I develop on a PC and remotely build to a Mac onto an iPad Pro with iPadOS 15.2.1. It works fine when I build to a physical iPhone 11 with iOS 15.1. I even get it to work on an iPad Pro emulator. I went through the entire documentation on Microsoft and that was no help. I attached a YouTube video of my issue to help better illustrate the problem.

My iPad is provisioned for development on my Apple Developer Account.

I have tried placing breakpoints before the Forms.Init in the AppDelegate.cs and it doesn't reach that point. It does, however, reach my launch screen before it crashes.

I have also created a quick project in Xcode with the same bundle Id and the quick project runs as expected.

I am using Xcode 13.2.1 and Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2337.

Thanks for any help in advance.

[Click here to see the issue](https://youtu.be/6rWrRlFpKbg)

Comment: "crashes on startup" would be a succinct description of the problem.  Have you looked at the logs?

Comment: Yes I have. Nothing seems too out of the ordinary. It even says "Launch succeeded. The app 'App' has been successfully launched on 'iPad'."

Comment: that's the VS output, have you looked at the device log in XCode?

Comment: Oh. That looks different. Logging a crash. Something about a 'SensorKit' not being found. Found out that this is a common issue with iPads.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue which reported here : https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/9938 .

The possible workaround is

1. Add `--weak-framework SensorKit` to the additional mtouch arguments.
2. Switch linking option between `Don't Link` and `Link Framework SDKs Only` .

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same result. I've even tried changing '--weak-framework SensorKit' to '--weak-framework=SensorKit.framework/SensorKit' per Github

Comment: Please add `-v -v -v -v` to the additional mtouch arguments in the project's iOS Build options  and upload a build log here ,see https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/9938#issuecomment-1021208043.

Comment: 'Link Framework SDKs Only' is the only one working for me

Answer (score 1):

As per the same github comment shown above the statement the mtouch arguement `--weak-framework=SensorKit.framework/SensorKit` worked for me instead of `--weak-framework SensorKit`

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do to work around this was set the deployment target lower (in my case 9.0) in my info.plist.